# Error when trying to list Matters using Google Vault API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Anyone come across this error when trying to use the Google Vault API using the Service Account OAUTH2 method?

```
HttpError 400 when requesting https://vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters?alt=json&pageSize=10 returned "The user does not belong to any Dasher customer."
```

Is Dasher a Google internal name for Postini?
I've gone over the API and service account permissions multiple times.

Comment: Can you able to put some codes that you work for so we can have a look. Base on your error on oauth2 you didn't have all those requirements for credentials so maybe because on how you setup your oauth is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add delegated credentials like so:

```
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('delegateuser@example.com')
```